# Dynamically change (or user change) the number of columns in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, bootstrap-4, custom-post-type

I'm trying to display a custom post type ' products' here:

[image]

The issue is, in the close future they will have 7 products which will leave one on a row on its own.

Is there a way I can alter the number of columns dynamically, So if there are 6 and under product it displays the posts I 3 columns, but if there are 7 items, it will display the posts section in 4 columns etc etc...

Or, is there a way I can allow the user to choose how many columns it displays in manually from the backend? I guess using something like Advanced Custom fields.

Ill be using a bootstrap based grid with a layout like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so if either needs to change this structure dynamically based on the number of posts OR based on the number a user selects from a dropdown in the backend, to:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this? I'm wondering if I'm overthinking it or indeed under-thinking it!

Thanks so much for looking!

PS - Heres what's I'm trying currently but it's not working...

```
<div class="container-flex our-products-strip">
<div class="lines-background-overlay" style="background-image: url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/background-stripes2.png);"></div>
<div class="container strip-padding">

<h2>Our Products</h2>
<hr class="hr-blue-more-bottom-space">

<div class="row justify-content-center">

  <?php
      $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'posts_per_page' => 9999,
        'orderby' => 'none'
      );
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  ?>

  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts()  ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>   


    <?php $data = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'products' ));?>
    <?php if(count($data) < 6 ){?>


    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 products-item-outer" style="--product-color: <?php the_field('product_colour'); ?>;">
    <div class="col-12 products-item-inner">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="click-overlay"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="logo">
        <?php 
        $image = get_field('logo_light');
        if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
          <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>          
      </div>    

      <div class="excerpt"><p><?php the_field('excerpt_text'); ?></p></div>
      <div class="read-more-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a><span class="arrow-right"></span></div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <?php }
    else{ ?>


    <div class="col-md-3 products-item-outer" style="--product-color: <?php the_field('product_colour'); ?>;">
    <div class="col-12 products-item-inner">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="click-overlay"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="logo">
        <?php 
        $image = get_field('logo_light');
        if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
          <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>          
      </div>    

      <div class="excerpt"><p><?php the_field('excerpt_text'); ?></p></div>
      <div class="read-more-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a><span class="arrow-right"></span></div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <?php } ?>


    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `php` then definitely you can put if condition to perform the check 
below is the example

```
<?php if(count($data) <= 6){?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
<?php }
else{ ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
<? } >
```

Comment: Ah fantastic! Thanks for that - I will read up more about the if else statement as I might want to add multiple conditions :) Thanks again.

Comment: I actually have one question - the condition inside the statement ($data) - will that work with a custom post type, or does that $data need to be replaced with the name of the custom post type?

Comment: @ShaunTaylor Data need to be replaced with your custom post data.

Comment: Hey Khalid, Im actually having trouble getting this bit of code to work inside my CPT loop... I've added the new loop to the bottom of the question, can you see where I'm going wrong at all? Its driving me crazy!! Sorry to come back on this :)

Comment: @ShaunTaylor What problem you are facing with it bro ? can you explain it a bit? and no need to be sorry, I'm happy to help you ;)

Comment: Thanks :) - I just can't seem to get it working, I've added your code it to my loop as per the code block I've added to my question, above, which should change the number of columns if the amount of posts displayed is below 6... but it just stays the same... Im not sure if I have integrated the code properly or if it will work correctly when its indie a loop...Also I changed the bottom bit of your code example to be <?php } ?> because this was not working: <? } > :)

Comment: Oh also, I don't quite think I know what should replace $data in your example?

Comment: Bro @ShaunTaylor replace your count line with this line count($data) < 6

Comment: Thanks again, but still nothing, Khalid :-/ here's my page, its the products strip I'm trying to effect... http://staging.jonassports.com I change the line to: <?php if(count($data) < 6 ){?> but as you can see, I now have 7 products displaying and its still showing as 3 rows instead of 4... is the line above the count correct do you think?

Comment: @ShaunTaylor Okay bro. Wait I'll look into your website

Comment: OK thanks! :) Ive just updated the code block at the bottom of my question with the latest code I'm using...

Comment: @ShaunTaylor bro in place col-lg-4 , replace it with col-lg-3  and it'll work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212079/discussion-between-shaun-taylor-and-khalid-khan).

Comment: @ShaunTaylor hi bro check out the new code in discussion chat